# How to change the text's color inside the TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter. How to change the text's color inside the TextField in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextField(
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.grey, // Change your color here!
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this,

```
TextField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
  decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.orange, filled: true),
)
```

Here text color is `red` and the background color is orange.